# CSS animation: Why is my spinning circle wobbling?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to create a simple loading animation using SVG and CSS but for some reason the spinning circle is slightly wobbling. It's hardly noticeable but it's driving me crazy.

Here's a link to Codepen demonstrating the problem: https://codepen.io/signorbusi/pen/dyeJqmE

This is the code:

```css
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#spinner {
  animation-name: spin;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="spinner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" stroke="black">
    <circle r="23" cx="24" cy="24" stroke-width="2"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Any pointers to how to get rid of the wobbling would be very helpful!

Comment: It doesn't appear to be wobbling in either the Codepen or the embedded Stack Snippet (in MacOS Firefox or Chrome).

Comment: No wobble in Safari IOS 15.4 iPad.

Comment: @omnibrain out of curiosity, did my solution fix your problem?

Comment: Weirdly if I run the code snipped here on SO I get no wobble, but if I open the link on CodePen I get a wobble. @codedude yes your solution works but I don't understand why

Answer (score 3):

The viewbox of the `<svg>` element is cutting off the edges of the circle as it rotates.  (Note that your `stroke-width` is increasing the size of the circle beyond the defined radius in the `r` attribute.)

If you expand the `<svg>` element's `width` and `height` attributes, match the `viewbox` attribute accordingly, and then also center the circle inside of that (using the `cx` and `cy` attributes on the `<circle>` element), it will not "wobble":

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="spinner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 60 60" stroke="black">
    <circle r="23" cx="30" cy="30" stroke-width="2"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Working Codepen can be found here: https://codepen.io/theodorewiersema/pen/NWMXowY

Comment: Your solution works, there is no more wobble. So that's great. But I don't understand the explanation, because my circle also seems to be fully inside the viewbox.

Comment: @omnibrain I suspect this may be a browser-specific rendering bug that is related to how circles and their strokes are aliases. In an attempt to make a "smooth" looking width 1 stroke around your circle, it may be "smoothing" it outside of the viewbox.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<circle r="22" cx="24" cy="24" stroke-width="2"/>
```

I changed the [radius attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/r) to 22 and it doesn't wobble.

Comment: It does wobble for me. Also, it would be helpful if you could explain why it should be working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).